# How to search for a value in line and check if it matches given condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file **in.txt**.

```
name="XYZ_PP_0" number="0x12" bytesize="4" info="0x0000001A"
name="GK_LMP_2_0" number="0xA5" bytesize="8" info="0x00000000bbae321f"
name="MP_LKO_1_0" number="0x356" bytesize="4" info="0x00000234"
name="PNP_VXU_1_2_0" number="0x48A" bytesize="8" info="0x00000000a18c3ba3"
name="AVU_W_2_3_1" number="0x867" bytesize="1" info="0x0b"
```

From this file i need to search for `number="0x867"` and check if it's info value matches to the expected given info value which is 0x0a. if it matches print matches else doesn't matches.

then next i need to search for `number="0x12"` and store it's info value i.e `info="0x0000001A"` and then search for `number="0x356"` and store it's info value  `info="0x00000234"` to another variable. this value should be equal to previous info value + 0x00000004 (i.e 0x0000001A + 0x00000004 = 0x0000001E).

**if** resulted value matches to  `info="0x00000234"` then print `number="0x12" info value 0x00000012 + 0x00000004 matches to info value of number="0x356".`

**else** `print resulted value not matching`

This is current attempt in python:

```
with open("in.txt", "r") as infile:

     XYZ = False
     MP = False
     AVU = False
 
     xyz = ['number="0x12"', 'info="0x0000001A"']
     mp  = ['number="0x356"', 'info="0x00000234"']
     avu = ['number="0x867"', 'info="0x0b"']

     for line in infile:
         if all(x in line for x in xyz):
            XYZ = True
            continue

         if all(x in line for x in mp):
            MP = True
            continue
 
         if all(x in line for x in avu):
            AVU = True
            continue
```

but this code will simply checks if the line is present in file or not. it won't check the conditions mentioned above.

Is there a way i can search for the number in the text file and store it's info value to variable?

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the code. (2) The code is syntactically incorrect due to nested double quotes. (3) You have to repeat the "in line" for the first string in the if-conditions.

Comment: I have fixed it. But is there in any way i can search for number="0x867"  and store it's info value to a variable and then compare it with another value.

Comment: You can use regular expressions (module "re") or use the "split" method of strings to split each line by spaces, look for the part that starts with "info=" and use slice notation to extract the hexadecimal part which you can finally store.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the double quotes, or you can use single quotes so that you string can have double quotes in it like this:

```
'number="0x12"'
```

Also, in your if condition the first part is wrong. Here is the loop:

```
xyz_list = ['number="0x12"', 'info="0x0000001A"']
mp_list  = ['number="0x356"', 'info="0x00000234"']
avu_list = ['number="0x867"', 'info="0x0b"']

for line in infile:
     if all(x in line for x in xyz_list):
         XYZ = True
         continue

     if all(x in line for x in mp_list):
         MP = True
         continue
 
     if all(x in line for x in avu_list):
         AVU = True
         continue
```

The all() function will check substrings in the line and returns true if all exist.

Comment: But this won't check the conditions mentioned above.

Comment: @V_S conditions about printing "matches" and "not matches" ?

Comment: No the code i given will just simply print if it matches or not what i wanted is mentioned above, that is searching a line and check if it satisfies a given condition.

Comment: @V_S you can use this regex [info=\"(.*)\"] to get the value of info and then store it in the variable.

Comment: my problem is i don't know how to search for the number in the file and then store it's respective info value to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the .txt file into dataframe and apply the conditions using the pandas datframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf('myfile.txt')
or 
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', sep=" ")
or 
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', ,delimiter="\t")
or 
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', sep=" ", header=None, names=["Pos", "Lang", "Perc"])
```